# VB Script to copy all sheet data one excel to another excel sheet

Tags: excel, vbscript

Is it possible to copy data from all the workbook sheets from one excel sheet (*ex: A.xls*) to another existing excel (*ex: B.xls*).

Can a logic be implemented, using VB, where it can do that no matter the amount of workbook sheets in A.xls (i.e. It should copy all the data of all pages of *A.xls* to *B.xls*)

I appreciate any kind of help, for I am not from a programming background.

Comment: Could you do a "Save As" to just create a duplicate version of A.xls?  Or when you say B.xls is existing, would it have to copy the tabs that are in A.xls to the end of B.xls (after any existing tabs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well After a lot of struggle and learning some basics i was able to get the code

Here is the code which works

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objPasteData = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\A.xlsx") 'Copy From File
Set objRawData= objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\B.xls")             'Paste To File
Set obj1 = objPasteData.WorkSheets("RawData") 'Worksheet to be cleared
obj1.Cells.Clear
countSheet = objRawData.Sheets.Count


For i = 1 to countSheet
    objRawData.Activate
    name = objRawData.Sheets(i).Name

    objRawData.WorkSheets(name).Select
    objRawData.Worksheets(name).Range("A2").Select

    objExcel.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
    usedRowCount1 = objExcel.Selection.Rows.Count

    objExcel.Range("A2:H" & usedRowCount1).Copy
    objPasteData.Activate
    objPasteData.WorkSheets("RawData").Select
    objExcel.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
    usedRowCount2= objExcel.Selection.Rows.Count

    objPasteData.Worksheets("RawData").Range("A"& usedRowCount2 + 1 ).PasteSpecial Paste =xlValues

Next
objPasteData.Save
```

Thanks @Nilpo & @rryanp for guidance.

Answer (score 4):

Though I'm starting to think you want to copy all the data across many tabs to one tab, if you actually want to keep the data on separate tabs, you can use something like this to loop through the worksheets in A.xlsx and copy them to B.xlsx:

```
Sub copy_sheets()
    Dim eapp As Excel.Application
    Dim wkbk_from As Workbook
    Dim wkbk_to As Workbook
    Dim wksh As Worksheet

    Set eapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wkbk_from = eapp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\Miscellaneous-DT\Excel\a.xlsx")
    Set wkbk_to = eapp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\Miscellaneous-DT\Excel\b.xlsx")
    eapp.Visible = True

    For Each wksh In wkbk_from.Worksheets
       wksh.Copy After:=wkbk_to.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Next wksh
End Sub
```

Comment: I'l just explain what my problem is. We get Raw data from Database in excel format in about 52 Excel Sheets. Each Excel Sheet has around a min of 30 Worksheet which varies on daily basis. We have a template file in which we copy the Raw data from all the worksheet from those 52 Excel documents we get. Its a tedious process to sit and copy all the data from those 52 excel into one sheet in that template file. So is it possible to do the copy paste using VB Script.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to copy all data from one worksheet to another is to use the copy and paste operation on a range that consists of all filled cells.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook1= objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test1.xls")
Set objWorkbook2= objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test2.xls")

Set objRange = objWorkbook1.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy
objWorkbook2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial objRange

objWorkbook1.Save
objWorkbook1.Close

objWorkbook2.Save
objWorkbook2.Close
```

Comment: @rryanp- Save As is not an option as we have around 50 Excel Sheets that we need to copy from to B.xls Also when i try to execute the code that u have given it says "Expected End of Statement" for line 2.

Comment: I'l just explain what my problem is. We get Raw data from Database in excel format in about 52 Excel Sheets. Each Excel Sheet has around a min of 30 Worksheet which varies on daily basis. We have a template file in which we copy the Raw data from all the worksheet from those 52 Excel documents we get. Its a tedious process to sit and copy all the data from those 52 excel into one sheet in that template file. So is it possible to do the copy paste using VB Script.

Comment: @Sriram That is *exactly* what I've given you.

Comment: @Nilpo- I copied you code and saved it as .vbs When i try to run it gives an error saying "Unterminated String Constant" on line 1.One doubt, the "Sheet 1" that you have mentioned thats the name of the sheet. So if i have 30 Sheets with different names in the excel book do i have to write those two statements 30 times giving those unique names?

Comment: There was a copy/paste error and it was using curly quotes instead of normal quotes.  I've fixed my code above to remove the unterminated string constant error.  As for the sheet names, you do not have to name them individually.  You can automate looping through them but I would need an idea of how your files are built.  You can also refer to them by number instead.

Comment: @Sriram--you'll probably have to use a combination of the code provided...Nilpos will copy the data as you want, and the code I posted will allow you to loop through each worksheet in a workbook.  You'll also have to build in something to keep track of or determine where the last row is in your destination sheet so the new tab's data gets posted below it and doesn't overwrite it.

Comment: Tracking where the pasted cells ends is easy.  It would be the same syntax I provided.  UsedRange will always return the range of filled cells, thus UsedRange plus 1 would be the next empty cell, etc.  He would also need to use the FSO and loop through his folder of input files.  I'll gladly write the code to do it but I need to know how the files are organized and what sheets need copied.

Comment: @Nilpo- I tried the updated code. I changed the "Sheet1" to the name of the Name that is there in A.xls book. When i execute the vb script it gives an error saying "Object Required:Set objRange = objWorkbook1.Worksheets("Module1").UsedRange.Copy" Code:800A01A8. But i see an option in the B.xls sheet saying "Select destination and press Enter to copy". And if i close the error window and press enter in the B.xls file the data is getting copied.
And the format is same in all the excel book in each workbook sheets. Headings are same only values are different.

Comment: Gr8 code! Got an error until I removed "SET" from "Set objRange". Then it worked. Thanks for the code - and for your patience with the "customer"!

Answer (score 0):

You say existing file b.xls, wbut if you overwrite everything, it doesn't matter so why not use

```
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CopyFile "a.xls", "b.xls", true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same task yesterday and had to spent a lot of time searching for the parts of the solution. From some reason in vbs named constants are not available (at least in newer Excel versions). 
The script below is tested and prooved to be working in newer Excel (2016)

```
outputFiletype = 51 'type_xlsx

' I assume you want to use the script for different files, so you can pass the name as a parameter
If Wscript.Arguments.Count < 1 Then
    Wscript.Echo "Please specify a name of the Excel spreadsheet to process"
Else
    inputFilename = Wscript.Arguments(0)
    outputFilename = Replace(inputFilename, ".xlsx", "_calc.xlsx")

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    ' if you want to make the excel visible (otherwise if it is failed it will hang in a process list)
    'objExcel.Application.Visible = True

    Set currentWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(inputFilename)
    Set newWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()

    i = 0
    For Each current_sheet In currentWorkbook.Worksheets
        If current_sheet.Visible Then ' copying only the visible ones
            i = i + 1

            Dim new_sheet
            If newWorkbook.Sheets.Count < i Then
                newWorkbook.Sheets.Add , newWorkbook.Sheets(i-1) ' after the last one
            End If
            Set new_sheet = newWorkbook.Sheets(i)
            new_sheet.Name = current_sheet.Name

            current_sheet.UsedRange.Copy
            new_sheet.Select
            new_sheet.UsedRange.PasteSpecial 13 'xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme - Everything will be pasted using the source theme
            new_sheet.UsedRange.PasteSpecial 8  'xlPasteColumnWidths - Copied column width is pasted
            new_sheet.UsedRange.PasteSpecial 12 'xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats - Values and Number formats are pasted.
        End If
    Next
    newWorkbook.SaveAs outputFilename, outputFiletype
    currentWorkbook.Close False
    newWorkbook.Close False
    objExcel.Quit
End If
```